# openvpn 2.2.1 error from SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations

Tags: openvpn, openssl

I am trying to use OpenVPN 2.2.1 on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) to connect to a VPN server maintained by a colleague. He uses TunnelBlick (on a Mac) successfully. I am trying to use his client configuration verbatim, the only changes being different files for the local peer. But I am getting an unhelpful error message (editing out private bits):

```
$ openvpn mycorp.conf
… OpenVPN 2.2.1 i686-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Mar 30 2012
… NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
… Cannot load CA certificate file mycorp-ca.crt path (null) (SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations) (OpenSSL)
… Exiting
```

The file in question (`mycorp-ca.crt`) is in the current directory; if I rename it, I get an expected error message (`…:fopen:No such file or directory:…`). It is readable by the current user and is an ASCII file:

```
----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
…18 lines of Base-64…
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The [code in question](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/browser/ssl.c?rev=05d11e3d79fafa19a06bf45652e39cb9bef5207a#L918) calls a library function in OpenSSL and it failed. The [library function documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html) just says, helpfully, that a return value of 0 from the mentioned function means:

> The operation failed because CAfile and CApath are NULL or the processing at one of the locations specified failed. Check the error stack to find out the reason.

Running `openvpn` under `strace` confirms that `mycorp-ca.crt` is being read. So what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was a missing hyphen (`-`) at the beginning of the file. When I add that, OpenVPN starts.